# Connect to LDAP from Javascript

Tags: javascript, ldap

I have an HTML page that includes some javascript code.
I would like to know how, using javascript code I can retrive the user name and the password from the LDAP active directory ?

how can I tell if the LDAP implementation on the computer i'm working with there is HTTP-based API?

Comment: If your LDAP implementation supplies an HTTP-based API, accessible to your client application, then yes. What do you know about your LDAP implementation?

Comment: This is usually done with server-side code (ie, PHP, C#, Python, etc.).

Comment: actually, I know nothing about that, where can I physiclly see that directory? and there is no way doing it using javascript?

Comment: how can I tell if the LDAP implementation on the computer i'm working with there is HTTP-based API?

Comment: Ask the admin, I wouldn't say it's common.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can't get user's passwords from AD. You can change them (if you have permissions), but you can't see them.

If you have an AD and you don't know how to use it, I can asume, there is a Sys Admin working with you. So, just ask him what going on with your AD and what do you have there.

I think, you shuld make server-side script. And then you can make an http-request from your page to your server and ask the server-side script to do what you need and return JSON as response.

And use google ;) [Like this](http://www.google.com/webhp?q=get%20all%20users%20from%20active%20directory%20c#&pq=c#%20and%20active%20directory)

Comment: Yes, I know, but this subject is all new to me so I don't not even where to start, so I wanted some guide lines to where to start and how to make it work. By the way, what is AD?

Comment: On what server your site/app/page is hosted? Is it like local server that works inside company network? Or it is a public server? And what OS are you using?

Comment: This is a server that work inside company network, and I'm using Windows 7

Comment: 'AD' - active directory.
Win7? on server?

Comment: Things you need to know (at least  to know what is it mian): 'JSON', 'JSONP', 'IIS', 'ASPX'.
If your server is windows something, then you probable have IIS. If you have IIS, then you can use ASP/ASPX. So just look for something like this:
http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/
http://code.google.com/p/jsonsharp/wiki/HowToConvertASPdotNETUserControlsToJSON
http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article454-using-pagemethods-and-json-in-aspnet-ajax.aspx
http://forums.asp.net/t/1222482.aspx/1